# Capistrano 3 Unicorn Start returning a strange error in the last step

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, capistrano3

I ran `$ cap production deploy` on my rails 5 application. It worked fine right up to the last step:

Seems like a permission issue to me, but it was working normally earlier.

```
unicorn:restart
      01 service unicorn_myApp_production restart
      01 Failed to restart unicorn_myApp_production.service: The name org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1 was not provided by any .serv…
      01 See system logs and 'systemctl status unicorn_myApp_production.service' for details.
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as marvin@bubbl.in: service exit status: 1
service stdout: Failed to restart unicorn_myApp_production.service: The name org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1 was not provided by any .service files
See system logs and 'systemctl status unicorn_myApp_production.service' for details.
service stderr: Nothing written

SSHKit::Command::Failed: service exit status: 1
service stdout: Failed to restart unicorn_myApp_production.service: The name org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1 was not provided by any .service files
See system logs and 'systemctl status unicorn_myApp_production.service' for details.
service stderr: Nothing written

Tasks: TOP => unicorn:restart
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The deploy has failed with an error: Exception while executing as marvin@bubbl.in: service exit status: 1
service stdout: Failed to restart unicorn_myApp_production.service: The name org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1 was not provided by any .service files
See system logs and 'systemctl status unicorn_myApp_production.service' for details.
service stderr: Nothing written

** DEPLOY FAILED
** Refer to log/capistrano.log for details. Here are the last 20 lines:

 DEBUG [b9413f29] Command: ( export RBENV_ROOT="$HOME/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.3.1" ; /usr/bin/env mv /var/www/myApp/releases/…
  INFO [b9413f29] Finished in 0.111 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [cef268ae] Running /usr/bin/env sudo service delayed_job_myApp_production restart as marvin@bubbl.in
 DEBUG [cef268ae] Command: ( export RBENV_ROOT="$HOME/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.3.1" ; /usr/bin/env sudo service delayed_job_bubb…
  INFO [cef268ae] Finished in 21.242 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [41580c64] Running /usr/bin/env sudo /etc/init.d/nginx reload as marvin@bubbl.in
 DEBUG [41580c64] Command: ( export RBENV_ROOT="$HOME/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.3.1" ; /usr/bin/env sudo /etc/init.d/nginx reload…
 DEBUG [41580c64]   [....] Reloading nginx configuration (via systemctl): nginx.service
 DEBUG [41580c64]   
 DEBUG [41580c64]   
 DEBUG [41580c64]   
 DEBUG [41580c64]   [ ok 
 DEBUG [41580c64]   
 DEBUG [41580c64]   
 DEBUG [41580c64]   .
  INFO [41580c64] Finished in 0.268 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [84d3bdae] Running /usr/bin/env service unicorn_myApp_production restart as marvin@bubbl.in
 DEBUG [84d3bdae] Command: ( export RBENV_ROOT="$HOME/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.3.1" ; /usr/bin/env service unicorn_myApp_produ…
 DEBUG [84d3bdae]   Failed to restart unicorn_myApp_production.service: The name org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1 was not provided by…
See system logs and 'systemctl status unicorn_myApp_production.service' for details.
```

Has anyone else faced this? What am I doing wrong.

Comment: Can you run it as the deploy user from SSH?

Comment: Nope. It errors out without a sudo.

Comment: Then I suggest @William Sumfest's answer. I'm not sure what changed in your system, but it is unrelated to Capistrano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a permissions error. In the last line:

```
/usr/bin/env service myApp start
```

Try:

```
/usr/bin/env sudo service myApp start
```